# AR(2) model, convert to smaller step size

Tags: arima, autocorrelation, arma

Given an AR(2) model with coefficients $\varphi_1$ and $\varphi_2$ and step size of 1.0, is there a possibility to compute new coefficients, but with a different step size (e.g. smaller, 0.5) so that the same autocorrelation function (ACF) is kept?

[image]

For an AR(1) model this is trivial, since the ACF is exponential.

Comment: If it is easy with AR(1), then recall that AR($p$) can be represented as AR(1). See [this](http://pareto.uab.es/lgambetti/Lecture2M.pdf) p. 5 for "companion form" for a VAR($p$) model; AR($p$) is just a special case of VAR($p$). Perhaps this could be useful. But what exactly do you mean by "so that the same autocorrelation function (AC) is kept"?

Comment: I added a plot, to show the AR2 fitted to the original data with step size 1.0, and the desired AR2 with half step size. This was done using numerical optimization to get the new $\varphi_1$ and $\varphi_2$

Comment: Did you figure out the way to do this? Could you share your findings? What about changes to step size for VAR model? Thank you